# How can use multiple controller as default: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two controllers that I want to use as default so how I can pass them into routes file.

I have done it like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user,home";
```

Can you please correct it.

Comment: How do two controllers work together to begin with...!?

Comment: You cannot use 2 controllers as default. There is no sense, since the default controller is a catch for all unprocessed URLs. Though you can define closure to setup custom route processing using special conditions.

Comment: if i merge the both controller in one file and then use that controller as default is it a good approach?

Comment: Ask yourself this: "I am typing URL of website. What should I see?" When you answer this one, you will get default controller.

Answer (score 1):

you must seperate your controllers. there is no way to use 2 controller as default.i wish this little info save some time for you